# Optimalization of if statements

Tags: c#

I'm trying to do the ifs in the loop. The compiler says that "Unhandled exception has occurred". Any ideas? The commented code is working. The one in for is not. The for is supposed to be more optimal.
EDIT: Sorry forgot to say that all ComboBoxes and TetBoxes are in arrays.

```
        ComboBox[] ComboBoxes = new ComboBox[3];
        ComboBoxes[0] = comboBox1;
        ComboBoxes[1] = comboBox2;
        ComboBoxes[2] = comboBox3;
```

The working code:

```
if (comboBox1.Text == "Cheese" || comboBox1.Text == "Vegetable" || comboBox1.Text == "Meat")
{
    if (comboBox2.Text == "Cheese" || comboBox2.Text == "Vegetable" || comboBox2.Text == "Meat")
    {
        if (comboBox3.Text == "Cheese" || comboBox3.Text == "Vegetable" || comboBox3.Text == "Meat")
        {
            return true;
        }
        else { comboBox3.Text = "Wrong input"; return false; }
     }
     else { comboBox2.Text = "Wrong input"; return false; }
 }
 else { comboBox1.Text = "Wrong input"; return false; }
```

The optimal not working version:

```
int isvalid = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    if (ComboBoxes[i].Text == "Cheese" || ComboBoxes[i].Text == "Vegetable" || ComboBoxes[i].Text == "Meat")
    {
        isvalid++;
    }
    else { ComboBoxes[i].Text = "Wrong input"; }
}

if (isvalid == 3)
{ 
    return true; 
}
else { return false; }
```

Comment: Oh. Sorry didn't paste the part where I declare them. They are all in arrays. Comboboxes and textboxes.

Comment: Ok, that changes things. I will delete my now irrelevant comments :)

Comment: Tip: replace last section with `return isvalid == 3;` - same thing.

Comment: ok Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int isvalid = 0;
List<string> foods = new List<string> { "Cheese", "Vegetable", "Meat" };
List<string> cbNames = new List<string> { "comboBox1", "comboBox2", "comboBox3" }; //If you have more than the three comboBoxes
foreach(Control cb in this.Controls)
{
    if(cb is ComboBox)
    {
        if(foods.Contains((ComboBox)cb.Text) &&  cbNames.Contains((ComboBox)cb.Name))
        //Only use the second condition if you have more than the three comboBoxes
            isvalid++;
        else
            (ComboBox)cb.Text = "Wrong Input";
    }
}
if (isvalid == 3)
    return true;

return false;
```

This uses a `foreach` which is where `cb` comes from, it is the same as looping through each comboBox, [here's some more info on foreach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx)

**After your recent edit this would now work better**

```
int isvalid = 0;
List<string> foods = new List<string> { "Cheese", "Vegetable", "Meat" };
foreach(ComboBox cb in ComboBoxes)
{
    if(foods.Contains(cb.Text))
        isvalid++;
    else
        cb.Text = "Wrong Input";
}
if (isvalid == 3)
    return true;

return false;
```

Comment: What's cb here?

Comment: I will add an explanation for you

Comment: This does check for invalid syntax but will it tell the user which one is invalid?

Comment: This is also assuming that there are only 3 combo boxes in the project. May have to check for specific cb's

Comment: @Hank that is of course true, though it is unlikely it would make a difference, as if there are other comboBoxes they will probably not say the values we are checking for

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre Which would result in those unrelated comboBoxes being filled with `"Wrong Input"` lol

Comment: @Hank now that you say it, you're right, I will add optionally checking for names

Comment: When I start the main function. The whole code quite big